# qemu для Windows (акселерация графики)

Tags: windows, gpu, qemu

Извините за сумбурный вопрос, так как накипело.. И в интернете ничего не нашел...

host: Винда 10

quest: Linux с графическим столом

Что нужно прописать в строке (или какие то другие варианты) чтобы нормально хоть ютуб в FF смотреть (не говоря уже о 3d)

`-accel hax` - для проца прописано
Может че, в `-vga` нужно прописать ... или другие варианты

В линуксе , знаю пробрасывают `-vga qxl`

У меня Nvidia Geforce на хосте, если че...

Comment: А проблема точно в графике, а не скорости сети? haxm не имеет IRQ_ON_CHIP - https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/334

Comment: Нет, сеть не причём.